# How to import one time global module that other module components can recognize

Tags: angular

I'm creating a project that is subdivided into different applications. As an example, I would like to use the authentication app.

First, let us define what I mean one time global module. As a minimal example, here are few lists.

1. `FlexLayoutModule`
2. `CustomUIModule`

These module must be declared once in the project. Here is the `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // Dependencies
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CustomUIModule,

    // Apps
    AuthenticationModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now let me show you the `AuthenticationModule`. I only had a login component for this module.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        LoginComponent
    ],
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

My problem here is `LoginComponent` cannot recognize `FlexLayoutModule` and `CustomUIModule` modules.However this can be solve IF you put those modules in the **import** option of the `AuthenticationModule`.

But man that is crazy, I don't wanna do that whenever i create another app and do the same thing, Since these modules are global type and **MUST DECLARED ONCE** . Can anyone have any solution how can i construct my application? Lot of thanks.

To be more specific i got `this error`:

```
Error: Template parse errors:'mat-[some-material-component]'is not a known element.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the guidelines : https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexLayoutModule} from './new-item.directive';
import { CustomUIModule } from './orders.pipe';

@NgModule({
 imports:      [  FlexLayoutModule,CustomUIModule, FormsModule, CommonModule  ],
 declarations: [ ],
 exports:      [  FlexLayoutModule,CustomUIModule, FormsModule, CommonModule   ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

By re-exporting  `FlexLayoutModule,CustomUIModule, FormsModule, CommonModule`, any other module that imports this `SharedModule`, gets access to exported members.

Comment: So by this, we can avoid writing these global type modules to every application modules *(e.g. AuthenticationModule, CatalogModule, OrderingModule, PaymentModule, ShippingModule.. etc.)*  by simply importing SharedModule. This might be a good answer.

Comment: @Shift'NTab - this as per doc , i dont know other way (that is not exists i think because if there is then there must be document is there but its not there )

Comment: Ill be testing this